# Is there a way to make QPlainTextEdit have rounded borders?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6

Creating a PlainTextEdit widget like this:

```py
self.textbox=QPlainTextEdit()
self.textbox.setStyleSheet("""border: 2px solid; border-radius: 20px;""")
```

Will clearly show that the textbox has rounded edges, only that something is preventing them from being shown (I think this might be the frame of the widget?)

[image: picture of textbox]

Given that the Qt documentation doesn't actually have a page for the PlainTextEdit widget, at least from what I've seen, how can I make the round edges actually appear?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I resolved this issue. Apparently, this is an issue dating back to at least 2016, where textboxes need to also have a background color change applied to allow the border radius to work properly.

Here's the fixed code:

```py
self.textbox=QPlainTextEdit()
self.textbox.setStyleSheet("""
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: palette(base);
        """)
```

Comment: Note: you should never set generic properties for complex widgets, otherwise they will propagate to all their children (for instance, scroll bars and context menus). Instead, you should always use explicit [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) (in this case, `QPlainTextEdit { ... }`).